# Cocoapods Private Spec Repo over HTTP/S3

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

We are looking at implementing a private specs repo for our commercial libraries, to be shared with external customers (i.e. it's a 'semi' private spec repo).

Is there currently a way to use HTTP (or more specifically S3) to host a spec repo? We don't have a public git repo (and due to it being a licensed product, putting it onto GitHub isn't really an option unfortunately).

There are some guides around pushing a git repo to S3, which looks promising, but it would be great to have native support in Cocoapods for using a HTTP specs repo.

Another alternative might be to supply the Podspec separately which points to a http source for the sdk download.

Is the git-repo-on-s3 route currently the only way to create such a spec repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods spec-repos are just interacted with by using the normal git tools, so as long as those work with the S3 solution it shouldn’t be a problem.

Did you try it and run into a problem?

Comment: Thanks... yep it seems to work fine. Would be good to be able to support a 'direct' podspec dependency over http (similar to the way static zip's can be linked), but all in good time :)