# Access pod hosted in private AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cocoapods

Is there a way to include the credential required by AWS S3 in Cocoapods specification?

currently my Podfile looks like this:
`'pod 'mylibrary', :git => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketThatHostsGitRepo'` and it works if the bucket has public access. However, once the repo is made private (i.e. requires authentication), mylibrary cannot be downloaded.

I've come across this post:
[Cocoapods Private Spec Repo over HTTP/S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082172/cocoapods-private-spec-repo-over-http-s3/47144412#47144412)
But a bit of detail would help as I poke around with .gitconfig and it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a username/password combo to the url path. Like:

```
'pod 'mylibrary', :git => 'https://username:password@s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketThatHostsGitRepo'
```

That's how I've done it in the past with 3rd-party private pods. I was provided the username/password, so I'm not sure where to get that part off the top of my head.